# Stateful constrictor Widget in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to do customized class using stateful widget and I have to use stateful because it have setState function however I want to add property for the class so, when ever I invoke the class I pass the colors I want or store the data I want I did the same for Rassed Button using stateless widget and it is works but for the statefulI have an error that the variable is undefined
I tried to invoke it using `widget.borderColor` but i have an error that the widget is not defined
here is the code :

```
class DoseDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  Color borderColor;
  Color hintColor;
  DoseDropDown({
    this.hintColor,
    this.borderColor,
  });

  @override
  _DoseDropDownState createState() => _DoseDropDownState();
}

String medicationDose;
List<DropdownMenuItem> getDropDownItem() {
  List<DropdownMenuItem> dropDownItems = [];
  for (String dose in medcationDose) {
    var newItem = DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text(
        dose,
        style: TextStyle(
```

here I am trying to use it :

```
color: hintColor,
```

and I have error that it is not defined

```
      fontSize: 23, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, 
        ),
      ),
      value: dose,
    );
    dropDownItems.add(newItem);
  }
  return dropDownItems;
}

List<String> medcationDose = [
  'مرة واحدة في اليوم',
  'مرتان في اليوم',
  'ثلاث مرات في اليوم',
  'اربعة مرات في اليوم',
  'وقت الحاجة'
];

class _DoseDropDownState extends State<DoseDropDown> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 70,
      width: 350,
      child: DropdownButtonFormField(
        dropdownColor: white,
        value: medicationDose,
        items: getDropDownItem(),
        iconSize: 50,
        iconEnabledColor: yellow,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            medicationDose = value;
          });
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            MyFlutterApp.pills__2_,
            color: yellow,
            size: 30,
          ),
          hintText: 'الجرعة',
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: white),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: borderColor,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
In this case, function `getDropDownItem()` is global and not in `class _DoseDropDownState` 
You can pass `hintColor` as a parameter 
You can in `DropdownButtonFormField` use  `widget.hintColor` and pass to `getDropDownItem`
code snippet

```
List<DropdownMenuItem> getDropDownItem(Color hintColor) {
...
child: DropdownButtonFormField(
        dropdownColor: Colors.white,
        value: medicationDose,
        items: getDropDownItem(widget.hintColor),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

String medicationDose;
List<DropdownMenuItem> getDropDownItem(Color hintColor) {
  List<DropdownMenuItem> dropDownItems = [];
  for (String dose in medcationDose) {
    var newItem = DropdownMenuItem(
      child: Text(
        dose,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: hintColor,
          fontSize: 23,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
      value: dose,
    );
    dropDownItems.add(newItem);
  }
  return dropDownItems;
}

List<String> medcationDose = [
  'مرة واحدة في اليوم',
  'مرتان في اليوم',
  'ثلاث مرات في اليوم',
  'اربعة مرات في اليوم',
  'وقت الحاجة'
];

class DoseDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  Color borderColor;
  Color hintColor;
  DoseDropDown({
    this.hintColor,
    this.borderColor,
  });

  @override
  _DoseDropDownState createState() => _DoseDropDownState();
}

class _DoseDropDownState extends State<DoseDropDown> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 70,
      width: 350,
      child: DropdownButtonFormField(
        dropdownColor: Colors.white,
        value: medicationDose,
        items: getDropDownItem(widget.hintColor),
        iconSize: 50,
        iconEnabledColor: Colors.yellow,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            medicationDose = value;
          });
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(
            Icons.home,
            color: Colors.yellow,
            size: 30,
          ),
          hintText: 'الجرعة',
          hintStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            DoseDropDown(
              hintColor: Colors.brown,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```